# RuntimeError: Function AddmmBackward returned an invalid gradient

Tags: pytorch

RuntimeError: Function AddmmBackward returned an invalid gradient at index 2 - got [100, 80] but expected shape compatible with [80, 80]

[image]

And my NN :
[image]

[image]

Comment: ##RuntimeError: Function AddmmBackward returned an invalid gradient at index 2 - got [100, 80] but expected shape compatible with [80, 80]

Comment: Hello Thanh, please read this post https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . You need to provide all necessary materials as code samples not as images. This typically requires posting a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example , i.e a small piece of code that anyone can copy-paste to reproduce your issue instantly. Please also provide the full stack trace in the question and not as an image

Answer (score 7):

It could be because of your neural network shape is not compatible to the previous shape.

Try changing your fc1 from `nn.Linear(in_feature=80, out_feature=80)` to `nn.Linear(in_feature=100, out_feature=80)`

Comment: What do you mean by  previous shape?

Comment: output shape of the previous layer